# The two separate codes above were made for manifest 2 background, but I can't pass it to 3

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

```
"background": {
        "scripts": ["sw.js","swTwo.js"]

  "background": {
    "service_worker": "sw.js"


chrome.webRequest.onCompleted.addListener(zeineth => {
  if (zeineth.method !== "POST") {
    return;
  }
  ;
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(zeineth.tabId, {file: "script.js"});
}, {urls: ["ETC..."]});

chrome.webRequest.onCompleted.addListener(cristinia => {
  if (cristinia.method !== "POST") {
    return;
  }
  ;
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(cristinia.tabId, {file: "scriptTwo.js"});
}, {urls: ["ETC.."]});
```

how can i edit below codes for manifest 3
so we can use only one service_worker
The two separate codes above were made for manifest 2 background, but I can't pass it to 3.

Comment: Why are you putting the manifest and two pieces of code together?

Comment: no, two backgrounds were used before and the plugin was working in this way, but after manifest 3 it did not work when I combined the two codes. so you can't use two service workers.

Comment: @SoMore - I'm a little confused. Why are the parameters named "zeineth" and "cristinia"? In the documentation, the name is "details", which is more descriptive. And it's the same event handler in both cases, so the function signatures should probably be identical. And why are there semicolons between the if-clauses and the calls to `chrome.tabs.executeScript()`?

Comment: Use chrome.scripting.executeScript. It has new syntax so refer to the documentation.

Answer (score -1):

```
  chrome.webRequest.onCompleted.addListener(zeineth => {
      if (zeineth.method !== "POST") {
        return;
      }
      ;
    chrome.scripting.executeScript({
      target: {zeineth: tab.id},
      files: ['script.js']
      urls: ["blabla.com"]
    });

    chrome.webRequest.onCompleted.addListener(cristinia => {
      if (cristinia.method !== "POST") {
        return;
      }
      ;
    chrome.scripting.executeScript({
      target: {cristinia: tab.id},
      files: ['scriptTwo.js']
      urls: ["blabla.com"]
    });
```

i changed it like this but i got url error

Comment: This is not an answer.  If you want to extend your oiginal question adding some detail, it's better to edit and add this content there. Please read [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)